# How to upload excel file without access ODBC driver

Tags: c#, asp.net, odbc

I am using access ODBC driver "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" in my ASP.NET Web application.
But I don't want to install the driver on each machine to use my Web App. Please suggest something to do to avoid installing the driver.

Comment: I could be wrong but if youre uploading the file I think you would just need the driver installed on the server?

Comment: The ACE driver is part of microsoft office.  The only other options is to use the JET (part of windows) which only works with xls files from office 2003 which has limitations of only 256 columns and 64K rows.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get around installing it. It is available as a redistributable - you will need to select the 32bit or 64bit depending what you built the app with. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Comment: Uploading is not the same as opening. For just uploading files you do not need odbc. If you want to read Excel, use EPPlus.

Comment: What is EPPlus, and again should I need to install on each machine..

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some kind of misconceptions here.

The WHOLE idea of a web server? Well,  you setup and install the required software and drivers and systems and software on the web server. Once done, then anything from a iPad to a smartphone to a computer ONLY requires a web browser. So client side software is simply a browser. Is that not why we like and use web applications?

However, if you going to use say SQL server on the web site? Then yes, you have to setup + install the appropriate SQL server drivers on that site.

And if you going to use MySQl on that web site? Then yes, you have to setup + install  the appropriate MySQL server drivers on that server hosting the web site.

And lo and behold? If you going to use Excel, or MS Access on that web site? Take a wild guess here? Then once again you have to setup + install the MS-access drivers on that web site.

So it not clear really what you are asking here?

But to answer your question?

If you going to use some kind of database on your server hosting the web site? Well then you have to ensure that the correct drivers are installed. How this works for MS-access, Oracle, MySQL, SQL server or any database is the SAME.

You simple have to ensure that such database systems and drivers are available on that server hosting the web site.

And if you looking to have this application work on other servers and web sites? Then of course once again, be it Oracle, MySQL, MS-access or any other database system? Then  you have to ensure the correct database drivers are setup and installed on that web server. How this works for ANY database system you plan to use is the same. MS-Access is not any kind of special exception here at all.